# Google maps event click listener

Tags: google-maps

I've been trying to create some polygon overlays on a Google map which, when clicked will link to another webpage in a new window. However it only ever links to the URL of the last-generated polygon. Any ideas why? I think I'm missing something basic, but is it to do with how I'm generating the polygons and then trying to pull the URLs from them?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var mapSquares = {};

  mapSquares['square1'] = {
    coords: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.572177, -0.247192), 
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.612177, -0.247192), 
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.612177, -0.347192),
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.572177, -0.347192)
            ],
    url: 'http://www.google.co.uk'
  };

  mapSquares['square2'] = {
    coords: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.522177, -0.247192), 
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.572177, -0.247192), 
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.572177, -0.347192),
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.522177, -0.347192)
            ],
    url: 'http://www.bbc.co.uk'  
  }

var allMapSquares;

function initialize() { 
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.572177, -0.247192); 
  var mapOptions = { 
    zoom: 12, 
    center: myLatLng, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
  }; 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions); 

  for (var mapSquare in mapSquares) {
    var drawMapSquare = { 
      paths: mapSquares[mapSquare].coords, 
      strokeColor: "#FF0000", 
      strokeOpacity: 0.8, 
      strokeWeight: 3, 
      fillColor: "#FF0000", 
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map 
    }; 

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawMapSquare, 'click', function() {
         window.open(mapSquares[mapSquare].url,'_blank');
    });

    allMapSquares = new google.maps.Polygon(drawMapSquare);

  }

}
</script>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you putted in for loop and passing the mapSquare as index for mapSquares[] array variable it taking last value because for loop iterated to and the last position of mapSquare was last so it will taking always last position according to your for loop thats why you getting always last link

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawMapSquare, 'click', function() {
     window.open(mapSquares[mapSquare].url,'_blank'); // here this will call when you click and at that time mapSqare position was last.
});
```

Comment: Ok. I see that now. So what would be the best way of getting around the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem and the simple way is: put the code blocks that actually creates an InfoWindow and adding the event listener to a separate function call. This will actually avoids the global and local variable problem.

The reason is explained in the answer of [Pratik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760489/pratik%20Pratik).